# Error when sending Email in WSO2 ESB

Tags: email, wso2-esb

I send Mail with WSO2 ESB 5.0.0

**1. I have uncommented the following line in Axis2.xml file**

```
<transportSender name="mailto" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportSender">
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.host">smtp.gmail.com</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.port">587</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.auth">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.user">lmphuong</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.password">password</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.from">lmphuong@gmail.com</parameter>
    </transportSender>

 <transportReceiver name="mailto" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportListener">
        <!-- configure any optional POP3/IMAP properties
        check com.sun.mail.pop3 and com.sun.mail.imap package documentation for more details-->
    </transportReceiver>
```

**2. Add content at messageFormatters in axis2.xml**

```
<messageFormatter contentType="text/html" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ApplicationXMLFormatter"/>
```

**3. I have create Proxy Service in WSO2 ESB**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="EmailSender"
       transports="http https"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <description/>
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log/>
         <property name="messageType"
                   value="text/html"
                   scope="axis2"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property name="ContentType" value="text/html" scope="axis2"/>
         <property name="Subject" value="Testing ESB" scope="transport"/>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
         <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <ns:text xmlns:ns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">$1</ns:text>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg value="Hello WSO2 ESB.....!"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <log level="full"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="mailto:ledung123@gmail.com"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
   </target>
</proxy>
```

**4. I recieved error**

```
ERROR - MailTransportSender Error creating mail message or sending it to the configured server
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:306)        
...    
[2017-09-15 08:04:05,945] ERROR - MailTransportSender Error generating mail message    
...
```

Please help me out how to soved this error

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there´s something wrong with your credentials (AuthenticationFailedException). Do you have any special chracters in your credentials? Or is there are proxy server between esb and gmail?

What you could do is start esb in debug/enable wire log to see the complete traffic. More info can be found here.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Debugging+Mediation#DebuggingMediation-Viewingwirelogs

Another option might be to use the GMail connector which can be found here.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Gmail+Connector
https://store.wso2.com/store/pages/top-assets?q=%22_default%22%3A%22gmail%22